# Why does PIP install of python-couchdb experimental branch from SVN fail?

Tags: python, deployment, virtualenv, fabric, pip

I'm setting up a Fabric/virtualenv/pip automated deployment for a project and I need to install the latest experimental branch of python-couchdb.  Naturally, I stick it in my pip requirements file, like so:

```
-e svn+http://couchdb-python.googlecode.com/svn/branches/experimental/httplib@195#egg=CouchDB-dev_r195
```

However, when I run my deployment I receive the following error and traceback:

```
[192.168.1.200] out: Obtaining CouchDB from svn+http://couchdb-python.googlecode.com/svn/branches/experimental/httplib/#egg=CouchDB (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
[192.168.1.200] out:   Checking out http://couchdb-python.googlecode.com/svn/branches/experimental/httplib/ to ./src/couchdb
[192.168.1.200] out:   Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory while executing command svn checkout -q http://couchdb-python.googlecode.com/svn/branches/experimental/httplib/ /home/sk/votersdaily/src/couchdb
[192.168.1.200] out: Exception:
[192.168.1.200] out: Traceback (most recent call last):
[192.168.1.200] out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pip.py", line 482, in main
[192.168.1.200] out:     self.run(options, args)
[192.168.1.200] out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pip.py", line 675, in run
[192.168.1.200] out:     requirement_set.install_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle)
[192.168.1.200] out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pip.py", line 2409, in install_files
[192.168.1.200] out:     req_to_install.update_editable(not self.is_download)
[192.168.1.200] out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pip.py", line 1970, in update_editable
[192.168.1.200] out:     vcs_backend.obtain(self.source_dir)
[192.168.1.200] out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pip.py", line 3420, in obtain
[192.168.1.200] out:     ['svn', 'checkout', '-q'] + rev_options + [url, dest])
[192.168.1.200] out:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.6.1-py2.6.egg/pip.py", line 4320, in call_subprocess
[192.168.1.200] out:     cwd=cwd, env=env)
[192.168.1.200] out:   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 621, in __init__
[192.168.1.200] out:     errread, errwrite)
[192.168.1.200] out:   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1126, in _execute_child
[192.168.1.200] out:     raise child_exception
[192.168.1.200] out: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here is what I know:

- The error relates to it not finding setup.py, as the files are never downloaded.  It seems to be refusing to create the path /home/sk/votersdaily/src/couchdb, but for other packages it has always created this path as needed.
- I can run as both root and as a local user and it fails the same.
- If I create the directory manually then it pitches a prompt telling me the directory is not currently an SVN repo and asking if I would like to overwrite it. If I wipe it out it still doesn't checkout the repo.
- I have reinstalled pip and recreated the virtualenv and the bug is reproduced.
- I can execute this pip install on my local workstation (in virtualenv) successfully.

Suggestions? I know this must be some sort of library or permission conflict, but I can't seem top pin it down,

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have subversion installed on that machine (stupid question, but just checking)? Are you sure that couchdb is nowhere else in the requirements file (e.g. you forgot to delete the original couchdb requirement after adding the subversion version of couchdb)?

Comment: ...subversion... yes... I suppose that is required to run that command isn't it... *sigh*

Comment: You should post so I can properly accept your answer, sir. In this particular case, the "stupid question" had great merit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per John Paulett's comment--you must indeed have subversion installed on the server in order to execute it on the server.

I would like the egg delivered to my face chilled, if possible.